# How to add multiple kernel versions to local repo manifest

Tags: android, git, repo, android-kernel

I followed this [link](http://elinux.org/Android_Kernel_Download) to create a local manifest to download a particular version of android kernel as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>

  <remote  name="aosp"
           fetch=".."
           review="https://android-review.googlesource.com/" />
  <default revision="master"
           remote="aosp"
           sync-j="4" />

   <project path="kernel/common" name="kernel/common" revision="android-4.4"/>
</manifest>
```

And synced using `repo sync kernel/common`

How should I proceed for syncing multiple kernel versions.

Comment: `repo sync kernel/common`  fetches all revisions by default. `git checkout <revision>` can switch versions.

Comment: After switching version and committing changes, `repo upload` says `no branches ready for upload`

Comment: `repo upload` needs some extra work like setting upstreams. So we usually use git commands instead, like `git push origin HEAD:<remote_branch>` for one repo or `repo forall -c 'git push origin HEAD:<remote_branch>'` for multiple repos.

Comment: `git push aosp HEAD:remotes/aosp/android-3.4` gives me error `To https://android.googlesource.com/a/kernel/common
 ! [remote rejected] aosp/android-3.4 -> aosp/android-3.4 (prohibited by Gerrit)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://android.googlesource.com/a/kernel/common'`

Comment: I don't know if you have the right to skip the review or to create a branch. Generally it should be `git push <remote> HEAD:refs/for/<branch>`.

Comment: I don't have the right to skip the review though. Does that mean I am left with solution by @gzh

Comment: If this is the official android kernel project, you may need to make a pull request to upload your work. If it is an internal project of your team, you need to know which branches you can access in your server's repo. Supposing it's a branch named `dev`, you can upload your changes via `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/dev`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [repo document](https://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html).

```
When you run repo sync, this is what happens:
If the project has never been synchronized, then repo sync is 
equivalent to git clone. All branches in the remote repository
are copied to the local project directory.If the project has 
already been synchronized once, then repo sync is equivalent to:
   git remote update
   git rebase origin/<BRANCH>
```

If you run repo sync, only a revision specified in your manifest will be checkout, but you can enter kernel/common folder to run git command such as `git pull` or `git checkout` to get version you want.

if you only want to use repo command, you can checkout kernel with different folder, i.e specify multi project with different revision in manifest as following.

```
<project path="kernel/common4.2" name="kernel/common" revision="android-4.2"/>  
<project path="kernel/common4.3" name="kernel/common" revision="android-4.3"/>
<project path="kernel/common4.4" name="kernel/common" revision="android-4.4"/>
```

Comment: Is it also possible to disable the default manifest without deleting the file. Otherwise a call to repo sync will download the entire source tree from default manifest.

Comment: @skylinedreamer .repo/manifest.xml is just a symbol link, you can change it to link to other manifest file. Or use local manifest to modify the original one.